# Command times out when executing

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

```
Laravel version:
8.x

PHP version:
8.0

MySQL version:
8.0

Server:
Larave Forge
```

I'm running a command on one of my websites

`php artisan command:here`

after a few minutes I get this status "Timed Out", is there anything that can be optimized here to prevent the time out?

`subscriptions` table has `40,000` records and `incomes` table has `8,000,000`. Every subscription has a maximum of `200` records in the `incomes` table.

To explain what this command does, this is fixing (by inserting) the lacking of income of every `ACTIVE` subscription, which will be identified based on the hour difference from the last income that has been inserted. Every subscription has a max of `200` records in the `incomes` table, so if the script detected that a `subscription` has already reached the `200` income records, it will update the `status` to
`COMPLETED`.

Subscription.php (model)

```
public function latestIncome()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Income::class)->latestOfMany();
}
```

Income.php (model)

```
public function subscription()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Subscription::class);
}
```

```
namespace App\Console\Commands;

class SomeCommand extends Command
{
    protected $signature = 'command:here';

    public function handle()
    {
        ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);

        foreach (Subscription::with('latestIncome')->withCount('income')->where('status', 'ACTIVE')->lazy() as $subscription) {
            $count_earnings = $subscription->income_count;
            $recent_bonus = $subscription->latestIncome;

            if ($recent_bonus) {
                if ($count_earnings < 200) {
                    $hour_difference = now()->diffInHours($recent_bonus->created_at);

                    if ($hour_difference > 1) {
                        $to_insert = 200 - $count_earnings;
                        $max = $hour_difference;

                        if ($hour_difference > $to_insert) {
                            $max = $to_insert;
                        }

                        for ($i = 0; $i < $max; $i++) {
                            $income = new Income;
                            $income->user_id = $subscription->user_id;
                            $income->subscription_id = $subscription->id;
                            $income->amount = (100 * 0.002) * 100;
                            $income->save();
                        }

                        if (($count_earnings + $max) >= 200) {
                            $subscription->update(['status' => 'COMPLETED']);
                        }

                        Log::info('Fix for:'.$subscription->id.' | User:'.$subscription->user_id.' | Total:'.$max);
                    }
                } else {
                    $subscription->update(['status' => 'COMPLETED']);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You might gain some speed improvement if you don't do the update for each subscription but rather in the end do `Subscription::has('income', '>=', 200)->update([ 'status' => 'COMPLETED' ])` (or maybe even at the start too to reduce the number of records).

Comment: @apokryfos I will update these line

`if (($count_earnings + $max) >= 200) {
    $subscription->update(['status' => 'COMPLETED']);
}`

// and
`$subscription->update(['status' => 'COMPLETED']);`

Comment: Yes if you use the above code you an remove those lines completely

Comment: Oh, it will update all subscriptions with 200 or more records, right? Am I right I need to pass a where. `Subscription::has('income', '>=', 200)->where('id', $subscription->id)->update([ 'status' => 'COMPLETED' ])`

Comment: I will post an example

Comment: @apokryfos thank you, appreciate that. That would be more clearer to me.

Comment: Is it loading the tables entirely into memory?  Does you app need all the rows at once?

Comment: @RickJames to answer your first question I think yes, to your second question, currently `lazy()` I think is loading all rows at once? what can you recommend optimizing my code? I see a performance issue it's slow.

Comment: @ThriveDigital - I can help with MySQL, but not with the layer between your app and the database.

Comment: @RickJames , do you need the whole query I'm executing? If yes, I can give it.

Comment: Yes, the SQL.  And `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: @RickJames , you can see view my query and create table here. https://www.toptal.com/developers/hastebin/akuqagiqaz.sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I think the subquery is the main sluggish part.
- This is not "sargable":  `AND  Date(`created_at`) >= '2022-02-04'`.  If possible, say

  ```
  AND created_at >= '2022-02-04'
  AND created_at  < '2022-02-04' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
  ```
- After the above, this index on `subscriptions` will be beneficial:

  ```
  INDEX(status, deleted_at, created_at)
  ```
- Oh, I found this hidden in a Comment; did you want that optimized?

  ```
  update  `subscriptions`
       set status = COMPLETED, 
           subscriptions.updated_at = 2022-02-14 17:53:10
    where  
    (
        SELECT  count(*)
            from  incomes
            where  subscriptions.id = incomes.subscription_id
              and  incomes.deleted_at is null
    ) >= 200
      and  status != COMPLETED
      and  subscriptions.deleted_at is null)
  ```
- It may benefit from these indexes:

  ```
  subscriptions:  INDEX(deleted_at, status)
  incomes:  INDEX(subscription_id, deleted_at)
  ```
- This will NOT work:  `updated_at = 2022-02-14 17:53:10`; the datetime needs quotes around it.  You might consider using `NOW()` instead of building the string.
- More importantly, that Update will, when there are more than 200, check each of the 200+ one at a time and update them -- 200+ times each!!  Work on rearranging the `UPDATE` to be a "Multitable" update where one table is a subquery something like this:

  ```
    SELECT subscription_id
        FROM incomes
        WHERE deleted_at IS NULL
        GROUP BY subscription_id
        HAVING COUNT(*) >= 200
  ```

That should make the Update run hundred(s) of times faster.

Answer (score 2):

You might gain some performance if you do your updates in bulk:

```
namespace App\Console\Commands;

class SomeCommand extends Command
{
    protected $signature = 'command:here';

    public function handle()
    {
        ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);

        // Update everything you can before the loop
        Subscription::has('income', '>=', 200)
                ->where('status', '!=' 'COMPLETED')
                ->update([ 'status' => 'COMPLETED' ]);

        foreach (Subscription::with('latestIncome')->withCount('income')->where('status', 'ACTIVE')->lazy() as $subscription) {
            $count_earnings = $subscription->income_count;
            $recent_bonus = $subscription->latestIncome;

            if ($recent_bonus) {
              $hour_difference = now()->diffInHours($recent_bonus->created_at);

              if ($hour_difference > 1) {
                   $to_insert = 200 - $count_earnings;
                   $max = $hour_difference;

                   if ($hour_difference > $to_insert) {
                       $max = $to_insert;
                   }
                        
                   // Some performance gain here possibly
                   Income::insert(collect()->pad($max, [ 
                         'user_id' => $subscription->user_id,
                         'subscription_id' => $subscription->id,
                         'amount' => (100 * 0.002) * 100,
                   ])->all());

                   Log::info('Fix for:'.$subscription->id.' | User:'.$subscription->user_id.' | Total:'.$max);
                }
            }
        }
       // Update anything that got pushed over that threshold
       Subscription::has('income', '>=', 200)
            ->where('status', '!=' 'COMPLETED')
            ->update([ 'status' => 'COMPLETED' ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, please wait while I'm reading the code, will try this on my local now.

Comment: Note I put `Income::create` instead of `Income::insert` initially which is probably wrong

Comment: Thanks, will update that when I try it. `Income::create` not `Income::insert`

Comment: Wait, did you say that wrong? you put `Income::insert` but in your comment you said instead of `Income::insert`

Comment: Yes initially I had `Income::create`, which I think is wrong. I then updated it  to `Income::insert` which is the correct one. Just let you know in case you got the code before the update

Comment: I have to load this right `use Illuminate\Support\Collection;` sorry, or this `
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;`

Comment: Sorry, I'm not that familiar with `Collection` I got this error now `Illuminate\Support\Collection::times(): Argument #2 ($callback) must be of type ?callable, array given`, I've checked the documentation as well https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-times

Comment: That's odd but check the update. The idea is to have some code to create an array which has  a `$max` number of elements.

Comment: Yea I think the update is accepting the `callable`, thanks for the updated answer @apokryfos, I will try that.

Comment: Thank you very much @apokryfos the `collect()->pad` fixed the error and it's inserting the correct no. from the `max`, however I need to add `created_at` and `updated_at` because it's not auto filling those.

Comment: Yes, `insert` is more of a query builder method so it wouldn't do some of the things that model methods do (like update timestamps or call model events). On the other hand it is faster when bulk-inserting.

Comment: Thank you very much @apokryfos, I've implemented your answer. I will run it now in my Laravel Forge server if it does not time out.

Comment: Forgot to mention, I also tried to contact Forge's support, and now I got a reply from James Brooks saying.. "The Commands panel has a time out of 2 minutes for commands to run in. It's not designed for long-running commands. You should SSH into the server and run this command manually.".. but this optimization we made is very  helpful to me as I've learned something. Thanks much @apokryfos

Comment: This sort of process does seem like it's more appropriate to run on a schedule if you are able to do that. You should still make use of @haseeb-hanif's answer in that case to manage the time it runs for to a reasonable number based on your expected workload.

Comment: hhmm I got this error now after I ran the command manually into my SSH
`SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction (SQL: update `subscriptions` set `status` = COMPLETED, `subscriptions`.`updated_at` = 2022-02-14 17:53:10 where (select count(*) from `incomes` where `subscriptions`.`id` = `incomes`.`subscription_id` and `incomes`.`deleted_at` is null) >= 200 and `status` != COMPLETED and `subscriptions`.`deleted_at` is null)`

Comment: time to add this in my constructor `set_time_limit(8000000);`?

Comment: Should I add it to another task schedule and run it once? then add `withoutOverlapping` to it?

Comment: @ThriveDigital yes a task should work. Normally you would not need to set a time limit for cron tasks as they usually run without a time limit. However if you do still see timeouts then do `set_time_limit(0)`. `withoutOverlapping` is also useful if you are worried that commands might overlap. The Lock timeout exceeded message might be an indication that there's another similar task already running

Comment: this line `Subscription::has('income', '>=', 200)
                ->where('status', '!=' 'COMPLETED')
                ->update([ 'status' => 'COMPLETED' ]);` , is causing timeout even I set the max execute time to 0, I think because it's fetching and counting ALL at the same time.

Comment: This should generate a query like: `update subscriptions set subscriptions.status = 'COMPLETED' where (select count(*) from incomes where subsciptions.id = incomes.subscription_id) >= 100 and status != 'COMPLETED'` it is not a fast query by any means but it should be at least as fast as doing `withCount('incomes')` (which as I am saying this realise you may not need to be doing anymore) . If the execute time is 0 and you get a timeout it might be a DB connection timeout so might want to check how long those timeouts are

Answer (score 1):

You can define a time limit in the __construct function or in your index controller if you want a large time restriction.

```
    public function __construct()
    {
        set_time_limit(8000000);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, @haseeb-hanif. I will try this one and will update you.

Comment: If this runs whilst overlapping frequently, you'll end up with many many processes and it will steal resources from your server FYI - there is no need for such a large execution time.

Comment: what would you recommend @Jaquarh

Comment: I do not know your environment, I 100% would not do it like this. I would do something like you would with pagination. I'd fetch 100 rows at a time on each cron and run it without overlapping

Comment: 8000000 is 92 days. That might be a bit too much. I mean you might as well set it to `0` to remove the time limit

Comment: Also, another point to note is if its taking a long time to execute, you're causing table locks which will effect your front-end service. Break it down, if it takes longer it takes longer but you're not risking resources or issues.

Comment: it's for an example @apokryfos. He can set what ever time limit he wants ...

Comment: Its a monotone answer, increasing execution time is a short term fix to a long term issue and the OP specifically asked for optimization - which this clearly is the opposite of. Fetch and execute in batches, schedule `withoutOverlapping` and decrease the time between the crons. Implement a fast exit strategy when there is no subscriptions left to amend.

Comment: @Jaquarh thank you very much, yes I asked for optimization, what can be improved and you told me some of it. I'm using lazy method you can see (https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#streaming-results-lazily)[here], I will also check the `withoutOverlapping`

Comment: @Jaquarh one thing, I'm running this manually because I only run this if I saw something wrong happen or reported like earlier I restarted the server, the task which is inserting the income of a subscription every hour failed. That's why I will run this script to fill those that are not inserted.